# How to show a set is compact on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have a set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined as $\mathbf{C} = \{(x, y) \mid x\in\mathbf{P}(y)\subset\mathbb{R}^3, y\in\mathbf{S}\subset\mathbb{R}_+\}$, where $\mathbf{P}(y)$ is a compact set on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for any $y\in\mathbf{S}$, and $\mathbf{S}$ is a compact set on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

For my problem, $\mathbf{P}$ represents a compact geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g., polygons and spheres. And $\mathbf{P}(y)$ represents the compact geometry obtained after enlarging $\mathbf{P}$ by a scale of $y$:

$\mathbf{P}(y) = \{yx \mid x\in\mathbf{K}\subset\mathbb{R}^3\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

Where $\mathbf{K}$ is a compact geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g., polygons and spheres. And $\mathbf{S}$ is $[10^{-4}, 10^4]$.

How can I show that $\mathbf{C}$ is a compact set on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not true. As a counterexample take $S = [0,1]$ and assign to each $y \in (0,1]$ the closed ball of radius $1/y$ and take for$P(0)$ an arbitrary compact set. Then the resulting set is unbounded and in particular it is not compact.

Comment: So what does the role of the closed ball play in $\mathbf{C}$? Also, that is not the type of problem I have in mind, I will update my question to better reflect what I was thinking about.

Comment: The closed ball is just the compact set that you associate to your $y$, i.e. the closed ball is your $P(y)$. The closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Where did this problem come from, please add more context…

Comment: Sure, I will add more context. @BrunoKrams, in my case actually $\mathbf{S}$ is something like $[10^{-4}, 10^4]$, so the closed ball would always have a bounded radius. In that case, is the set still unbounded?

Comment: I think it would be helpfull if you give your explicit definition of $P(y)$. It seems that you start with some compact set, say $K$, and $P(y)$ is just $y$ times $K$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: This is crucial. Scaling is a continuous mapping. You can now proceed as follows:
Define $\phi : K \times S \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ by $\phi(a,b) = (ba, b)$. Then $\phi$ is continuous and $C$ is the image of $K \times S$ under $\phi$.

Comment: That makes sense! If you are willing to type this down as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\phi : \mathbf{K} \times \mathbf{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ by $\phi(a,b) = (ba, b)$. Then $\phi$ is continous and $\mathbf{C}$ is just the image of the compact set $\mathbf{K} \times \mathbf{S}$ under $\phi$, hence $\mathbf{C}$ is compact.